# Change image gallery based on product name (set boolean value to true)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, nopcommerce

I am developing a site in nopcommerce. i wish to change the image gallery depending on product name. for example if the product name contains *Flowers* display gallery 1 else display gallery 2

i have currently written the code

```
@Html.Widget("productdetails_top")
        @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Product", new { SeName = Model.SeName }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "product-details-form" }))
        {
            @helper renderProductLine(ProductDetailsModel.ProductVariantModel product)
            {
                if (product.Name.Contains("Flowers"))
                {
                    bool isFlowersGallery = true;  
                }        

            <div class="product-essential">
                @Html.Widget("productdetails_before_pictures")
                <!--product pictures-->


              @if (isFlowersGallery)
                {
```

I am now getting the error isFlowersGallery does not exist in the current context.

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: without wishing to pour scorn on your approach, i think you should try to find a solution based on categorising your products by type. this will be an endless frustration for you to go down this path.

Comment: Thanks, how would i go about this?

Comment: alas, this was a comment (rather than answer) as I have no experience in nop. i highly recommend becoming aufait with it as you'll potentially spend days hardcodong edge-cases, when perhaps an hour's admin would have solved your problem and futureproofed your product line

Comment: iv now gone down the apporach as @jimtollan suggested  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450095/how-to-write-an-if-statement-with-value-from-database-mvc-nopcommerce

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the declaration of isFlowersGallery out:

```
        bool isFlowersGallery;

        @helper renderProductLine(ProductDetailsModel.ProductVariantModel product)
        {
            if (product.Name.Contains("Flowers"))
            {
                isFlowersGallery = false;  
            }
```

Comment: thanks, have moved the declaration as suggested but still the same error.

Comment: listen, your logic is completely wrong, so you'll never get the correct *gallery* here. you are saying: `if (product.Name.Contains("Flowers"))` then set `isFlowersGallery = false;`

Comment: thanks jim, even if the if statement is set to true i still get the same error.

Comment: i unfortunately have no experience with nop, but would highly recommend stepping back a few paces and looking at some way of tagging/categorising your products as this hardcoded logic will get messy and hard to test. sorry :_(